# long running task in Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a web service(written in java springboot) where a request for creating  some resource comes and resource takes a long time to get create~5-6 hours.And after resource creation , I need to invoke some endpoint to notify creation.

There are multiple approach to handle this

1. once request to create resource comes, store this in database and return 200ok to client and have a long running task in background which polls the database and process new tasks and at completion notify end point.
   Here challenge is how to handle failure of web node , how to take handle concurrent read of multiple poller tasks running in parallel on multiple web nodes behind elb.

2.second approach is to decouple the two ,make polling in separate stack just plain worker nodes instead in rest service but challenge of locking and failover strategy is still there.

Which approach of the above 2 is better and how to handle lock to avoid concurrent execution of same create resource by multiple poller task and handle failure scenario also?

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is based on my opinion and there can be hundreds of different way to do the job.**

Just don't use polling from db, it has some disadvantages when it comes to concurrency while scaling application. Because you need to accomplish some locking mechanisms to prevent processing same data. Instead of use async messaging with message brokers.

Take the data make validations and save it to db and then publish an event something like XResourceCreatedEvent into rabbitmq or similar message broker.

Write a consumer which listens XResourceCreatedEvent event and do the long running task and invoke the endpoint inside that consumer.

Take a look at spring boot and rabbitmq : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/